# Intercalar dos arrays javascript

Tags: javascript

Alguien me podría ayudar a resolver esto? No entiendo como hacerlo, intento hacerlo con `for` pero no logro intercalarlos.

Debés crear una función llamada `arrayHandler` que reciba dos arreglos de igual largo como parámetros y muestre en la consola:
`Soy {elemento de array 1} y yo soy {elemento de array 2}`.

Ejemplo:
`arrayHandler([1,2,3,4], [“h”,”o”,”l”,”a”])` debe mostrar:

> ```
> Soy 1 y yo soy h
> Soy 2 y yo soy o
> Soy 3 y yo soy l
> Soy 4 y yo soy a
> ```

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y mostrar lo que intestaste, para ver qué está mal. Solo tienes que concatenar `array1[i]` y `array2[i]`, donde `i` es la variable iteradora del `for`.

Answer (score 2):

Simplente recorres en un for la longitud de cualquiera de los dos ya que tiene la misma longitud, al recorrer cada posicion haces log de cada array en la posición de i, esto

```
console.log("Soy:"+array1[i]+" y yo soy:"+array2[i]);
```

es equivalente a

```
console.log("Soy:"+array1[0]+" y yo soy:"+array2[0]);
console.log("Soy:"+array1[1]+" y yo soy:"+array2[1]);
console.log("Soy:"+array1[2]+" y yo soy:"+array2[2]);
console.log("Soy:"+array1[3]+" y yo soy:"+array2[3]);
```

**La respuesta**

```js
function arrayHandler(array1,array2){
if(array1.length===array2.length)
 {
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) 
    {
       console.log("Soy:"+array1[i]+" y yo soy:"+array2[i]);
    }
  }
}

arrayHandler([1,2,3,4], ['h','o','l','a']);
```